# PostgreSQL owner/role administration for QGIS projects

Tags: qgis, postgresql

What's the best way to administrate PostgreSQL roles for QGIS projects? I've created a separte schema for each of my QGIS projects. Is it possible to revoke all privileges except "select" for finished projects?

Comment: Sure, obviously you cannot edit your postgres spatial tables.

Comment: I'm not sure for QGIS, in Esri you can, so that means it must be possible. I use one *database* for each project and have defined Viewer, Editor, Administrator (owner) roles so it's kinda easy to revoke update from Editor for a whole database. Note that each login role should have it's own schema to play in (scratch space).. I'm not sure about changing just one schema though I suspect the theory is the same.